# Integrating ChatGPT and Google Assistant on Google Home devices using n8n

Tags: oauth-2.0, integration, openai-api, google-home, n8n

I hope this is sufficient detail, but feel free to let me know if more information would help. This is a "Can I accomplish this and if so, how?" question.

**What I want to happen:** I say, "Hey Google, ask GPT " then Google sends the query to my n8n instance (self-hosted). I use an n8n workflow to contact the ChatGPT API to resolve the query and return the response to Google, who then returns it to my Google device and it speaks the result.

I thought this would be an interesting and useful project, but it's already taken too much of my time to complete.

**What is actually happening:** Essentially, nothing. Google is not working with n8n for this purpose.

**What I have done so far:** I set up a workflow in n8n. I have an OpenAI key. I have a Google cloud / actions console account. I have a certificate with certbot and n8n is using it. I've opened ports 80 and 443 and exposed n8n. I've (sort of) filled out the OAuth2 / App questionnaire Google requires, it let me submit, but I left a lot of it blank. I generated an OAuth2 ID and secret in n8n, I tried to put it into Google and it wants a scope. I cannot figure what scope to use or if I am even doing this right at all at this point.

**What I would like someone to tell me:**

- What scope do I use?
- What are the steps that allow n8n to answer voice queries from a Google Home device (speaker, nest hub, mini).

**Concerns I have:**
Is what I am trying to do possible still? I see lots of instructions using DiagFlow, but it's gone since 6/13/2023. I can't find a current guide on how to set this up, which is surprising to me, I thought it would be a popular venture. Maybe I am not searching using the right words, so a link to a current, working guide would be great!

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code isn't really relevant, it's Google config usage in n8n. I will, however, go ask on google forums and n8n forums.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up. Conversational actions are no longer available ([sunset on 6/13/2023](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset/faq#what_will_happen_to_the_assistant_directory_after_sunset)) which means you won't be able to build, edit or deploy Conversational Actions with Dialogflow.
Unfortunately, custom interactions with Assistant are not possible anymore.

Comment: Google's getting out of his business I guess